# Allow outgoing connection to remote server through SSH

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm a newbie in using Linux. Currently I am in the process of moving my Wordpress site to a new dedicated server running Linux. When I logged on to the Wordpress site as admin, I noticed the following messages:

```
RSS Error: WP HTTP Error: Failed to connect to 1xx.1xx.xxx.xxx: Permission denied
RSS Error: WP HTTP Error: Failed to connect to xx.xxx.xx.xxx: Permission denied
```

A Google search showed that the outgoing connection to the remote server was blocked. Now I would like to use SSH to allow the server to connect to WordPress so that the RSS will feeds  correctly by the IP 1xx.1xx.xxx.xxx above. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you update your question to explain in detail what connects to what and what is hosted where ? I don't really understand your architecture here.

Comment: @Kwaio, what I want is to allow permissions to access remote IP connection.

Comment: Please explain in detail (with a schema?) which servers are involved and which way the SSH connection should go. Please also add the content of /etc/ssh/sshd_config on remote server.